# Fetching AWS Marketplace entitlements after SaaS subscription

Tags: aws-sdk, entitlements, aws-marketplace

1. A customer subscribes to my SaaS product on AWS Marketplace and is redirected to my registration form
2. My registration form receives the registration token and exchanges it for the product code and customer identification via the `ResolveCustomer` method of the **AWS Marketplace Metering Service**

If I understood the AWS documentation correctly this means that now the subscription is active from the perspective of AWS Marketplace, right?

Does this also mean that if I fetch entitlements with the **AWS Marketplace Entitlement Service** for that same customer they will already be returned without an intermediate step?

*The intermediate step being some kind of additional verification or confirmation procedure/API call.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription starts already at the redirect (order confirmation).

Yes, entitlements are available right away, after the subscription starts.

There is no intermediate step.